# Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string in phantomjs

Tags: node.js, phantomjs

I've encountered following error when I run my code,

```
Error: /var/www/courses.com.mm/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs: 1: /var/www/mysite.com.mm/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string

    at Socket.onStderr (/var/www/mysite.com.mm/node_modules/phridge/lib/spawn.js:93:28)
    at emitOne (events.js:101:20)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:176:18)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:134:10)
    at Pipe.onread (net.js:547:20)
```

Please let me know how to solve it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens when we build in local and push to host phantomjs.

```
## base image
FROM node:10.16

ADD ./Resources/node_modules /tmp/node_modules

RUN mkdir /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh"]
```

Now Build and exec Docker then go to Docker Terminal and remove all node modules and do `npm install` inside docker

Answer (score 1):

See the following issues on GitHub:

- https://github.com/Medium/phantomjs/issues/392
- https://github.com/Medium/phantomjs/issues/384

It seems you have installed the binary on 1 platform and run them on another. According to docs NPM expects you to run `npm rebuild` if you switch platforms, to rebuild any platform-specific dependencies.

see also https://github.com/Medium/phantomjs#cross-platform-repositories for more information.